# 1 class inherits 2 different metaclasses (abcmeta and user defined meta)

Tags: python, metaprogramming, metaclass

I have a class1 that needs to inherit from 2 different metaclasses which is Meta1 and abc.ABCMeta

Current implementation:

Implementation of Meta1:

```
class Meta1(type):
    def __new__(cls, classname, parent, attr):
        new_class = type.__new__(cls, classname, parent, attr)
        return super(Meta1, cls).__new__(cls, classname, parent, attr)
```

implementation of class1Abstract

```
class class1Abstract(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta1
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
```

implementation of mainclass

```
class mainClass(class1Abstract):
    # do abstract method stuff
```

I know this is wrong to implement 2 different meta twice.

I change the way metclass is loaded (a few tries) and I get this
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases

```
metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

I ran out of ideas...

---

### `EDITED 1`

I tried this solution it works but the mainClass is not an instance of class1Abstract

```
print issubclass(mainClass, class1Abstract) # true
print isinstance(mainClass, class1Abstract) # false
```

Implementation of class1Abstract

```
class TestMeta(Meta1):
    pass


class AbcMeta(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
    pass


class CombineMeta(AbcMeta, TestMeta):
    pass


class class1Abstract(object):
    __metaclass__ = CombineMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def do_shared_stuff(self):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def test_method(self):
        ''' test method '''
```

Implementation of mainClass

```
class mainClass(class1Abstract):
    def do_shared_stuff(self):
        print issubclass(mainClass, class1Abstract) # True
        print isinstance(mainClass, class1Abstract) # False
```

Since mainClass inherits from an abstract class python should complain about test_method not being implemented in mainClass. But it doesn't complain anything because print isinstance(mainClass, class1Abstract) # False

`dir(mainClass)`
doesn't have

```
['__abstractmethods__', '_abc_cache', '_abc_negative_cache', '_abc_negative_cache_version', '_abc_registry']
```

HELP!

---

### `EDITED 2`

Implementation of class1Abstract

```
CombineMeta = type("CombineMeta", (abc.ABCMeta, Meta1), {})
class class1Abstract(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def do_shared_stuff(self):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def test_method(self):
        ''' test method '''
```

Implementation of mainClass

```
class mainClass(class1Abstract):
    __metaclass__ = CombineMeta
    def do_shared_stuff(self):
        print issubclass(mainClass, class1Abstract) # True
        print isinstance(mainClass, class1Abstract) # False
```

`dir(mainClass)` now have abstractmethod's magic methods

```
['__abstractmethods__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__metaclass__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_abc_cache', '_abc_negative_cache', '_abc_negative_cache_version', '_abc_registry', 'do_shared_stuff', 'test_method']
```

But python doesn't warn about test_method not being instantiated

HELP!

Comment: Is this python 2 only?

Comment: So your main problem is that `mainClass` does not complain that the abstract methods are not instantiated? I believe python doesn't provide a way around this. Rather than getting an error at class creation time, you get the error at object creation time ie. `mainClass()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default python only complains that class has abstract methods when you attempt to instantiate the class, not when you create the class. This is because the class's metaclass is still `ABCMeta` (or subtype thereof), so it's permitted to have abstract methods.

To get what you want you would need to write your own metaclass that raises an error when it spots that `__abstractmethods__` isn't empty. This way you have to explicitly state when a class is no longer allowed abstract methods.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class YourMeta(type):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourMeta, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print "YourMeta.__init__"
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        newcls = super(YourMeta, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        print "YourMeta.__new__"
        return newcls

class ConcreteClassMeta(ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ConcreteClassMeta, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.__abstractmethods__:
            raise TypeError("{} has not implemented abstract methods {}".format(
                self.__name__, ", ".join(self.__abstractmethods__)))

class CombinedMeta(ConcreteClassMeta, YourMeta):
    pass

class AbstractBase(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def f(self):
        raise NotImplemented

try:
    class ConcreteClass(AbstractBase):
        __metaclass__ = CombinedMeta

except TypeError as e:
    print "Couldn't create class --", e

class ConcreteClass(AbstractBase):
    __metaclass__ = CombinedMeta
    def f(self):
        print "ConcreteClass.f"

assert hasattr(ConcreteClass, "__abstractmethods__")
c = ConcreteClass()
c.f()
```

Which outputs:

```
YourMeta.__new__
YourMeta.__init__
Couldn't create class -- ConcreteClass has not implemented abstract methods f
YourMeta.__new__
YourMeta.__init__
ConcreteClass.f
```

Comment: Isn't `ConcreteClassMeta` redundant? Won't `ABCMeta.__init__` do the check? i.e. won't `class CombinedMeta(ABCMeta, YourMeta)` be sufficient?

Answer (score 15):

In Python, every class can only have one metaclass, not many. However, it is possible to achieve similar behaviour (like if it would have multiple metaclasses) by mixing what these metaclasses **do**.

Let's start simple. Our own metaclass, simply adds new attribute to a class:

```
class SampleMetaClass(type):
  """Sample metaclass: adds `sample` attribute to the class"""
  def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
    dct['sample'] = 'this a sample class attribute'
    return super(SampleMetaClass, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct)

class MyClass(object):
  __metaclass__ = SampleMetaClass

print("SampleMetaClass was mixed in!" if 'sample' in MyClass.__dict__ else "We've had a problem here")
```

This prints "SampleMetaClass was mixed in!", so we know our basic metaclass works fine.

Now, on the other side, we want an abstract class, in its simplest it would be:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class AbstractClass(object):
  __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
  @abstractmethod
  def implement_me(self):
    pass

class IncompleteImplementor(AbstractClass):
  pass

class MainClass(AbstractClass):
  def implement_me(self):
    return "correct implementation in `MainClass`"

try:
  IncompleteImplementor()
except TypeError as terr:
  print("missing implementation in `IncompleteImplementor`")

MainClass().implement_me()
```

This prints "missing implementation in `IncompleteImplementor`" followed up by "correct implementation in `MainClass`". So, the abstract class also works fine.

Now, we have 2 simple implementations and we need to mix together the behaviour of the two metaclasses. There are multiple options here.

**Option 1 - subclassing**

One can implement a `SampleMetaClass` as a subclass of `ABCMeta` - metaclasses are also classes and one can inhereit them!

```
class SampleMetaABC(ABCMeta):
  """Same as SampleMetaClass, but also inherits ABCMeta behaviour"""
  def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
    dct['sample'] = 'this a sample class attribute'
    return super(SampleMetaABC, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct)
```

Now, we change the metaclass in the `AbstractClass` definition:

```
class AbstractClass(object):
  __metaclass__ = SampleMetaABC
  @abstractmethod
  def implement_me(self):
    pass

# IncompleteImplementor and MainClass implementation is the same, but make sure to redeclare them if you use same interpreter from the previous test
```

And run both our tests again:

```
try:
  IncompleteImplementor()
except TypeError as terr:
  print("missing implementation in `IncompleteImplementor`")

MainClass().implement_me()

print("sample was added!" if 'sample' in IncompleteImplementor.__dict__ else "We've had a problem here")
print("sample was added!" if 'sample' in MainClass.__dict__ else "We've had a problem here")
```

This would still print that `IncompleteImplementor` is not correctly implemented, that `MainClass` is, and that both now have the `sample` class-level attribute added. Thing to note here that `Sample` part of the metaclass was successfully applied to the `IncompleteImplementor` as well (well, there is no reason it wouldn't).

As it would be expected, `isinstance` and `issubclass` still work as supposed to:

```
print(issubclass(MainClass, AbstractClass)) # True, inheriting from AbtractClass
print(isinstance(MainClass, AbstractClass)) # False as expected - AbstractClass is a base class, not a metaclass
print(isinstance(MainClass(), AbstractClass)) # True, now created an instance here
```

**Option 2 - composing metaclasses**

In fact, there is this option in the question itself, it only required a small fix. Declare new metaclass as a composition of several simpler metaclasses to mix their behaviour:

```
SampleMetaWithAbcMixin = type('SampleMetaWithAbcMixin', (ABCMeta, SampleMetaClass), {})
```

As previously, change the metaclass for an `AbstractClass` (and again, `IncompleteImplementor` and `MainClass` don't change, but redeclare them if in same interpreter):

```
class AbstractClass(object):
  __metaclass__ = SampleMetaWithAbcMixin
  @abstractmethod
  def implement_me(self):
    pass
```

From here, running same tests should yield same results: `ABCMeta` still works and ensures that `@abstractmethod`-s are implemented, `SampleMetaClass` adds a `sample` attribute.

I personally prefer this latter option, for the same reason as I generally prefer composition to the inheritance: the more combinations one eventually needs between multiple (meta)classes - the simpler it would be with composition.

**More on metaclasses**

Finally, the best explanation of metaclasses I've ever read is this SO answer:
[What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python#answer-6581949)

Comment: i don't think these solution work as abstract method is checked at class creation.

Comment: Well, this is a separate issue - the fact that implementation is verified at instantiation time only is how the ABCMeta is implemented. Otherwise you would need some kind of "hook" being set-up on class declaration - I'm not sure if this exists, but please someone correct me if I'm wrong here. If you really want to force this check, you can attempt creating a class instance just after its declaration, but this would be still coder's responsibility of doing so. On the other hand - why exactly would one need this? Maybe there is other way of fulfilling the same need?

Answer (score 0):

No need to set two metaclasses: `Meta1` should inherit from `abc.ABCMeta`.

Answer (score 0):

In your EDITED code (both 1 and 2), you are almost done. The only wrong thing is how you use `isinstance`. You want to check whether a class instance (in this case `self`) is an instance of a given class (`class1Abstract`). For example:

```
class mainClass(class1Abstract):
def do_shared_stuff(self):
    print issubclass(mainClass, class1Abstract) # True
    print isinstance(self, class1Abstract) # True
```